# How to kill multiple PIDs with one script and make it return to prompt

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pid

I have two PID that are running in my linux server.

When I do followin command they give me back the PID:

```
pgrep -f -d ' ' /'main.py'
```

`4752 4768`

And here they are with command: **ps -ef | grep main.py**

```
ubuntu    4752  4749  3 08:07 pts/1    00:00:04 python /home/ubuntu/deploy/main.py 
ubuntu    4768  4752  5 08:07 pts/1    00:00:05 /home/ubuntu/venvs/myvirtual/bin/python /home/ubuntu/deploy/main.py
```

Now, I wanted to write a small shell script that when I run it, It will kill both PIDs. My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

PID=`pgrep -f -d ' ' /'main.py'`

if [ -z "$PID" ]; then
    echo "no pid found for main.py"
else
    echo -ne '\n' | nohup kill -KILL $PID 1>&2 &
fi
```

**The problem is, when I run this script (./shutdown.sh) .. it first prints this:**

```
-bash: line 56:  4727 Killed   nohup python ~/deploy/main.py > /home/ubuntu/main.log 2>&1
```

**... then I have to press [ENTER] to get back to prompt and it then prints:**

```
[1]+  Exit 137  . ~/venvs/myvirtual/bin/activate && nohup python ~/deploy/main.py > /home/ubuntu/main.log 2>&1  (wd: ~/deploy)
(wd now: ~)
```

1) How do I make it kill the PIDs and just return to prompt cleanly without me hitting a RETURN button after script is run?

2) Is there also a way to make the script fail if PID killing does not happen?

Comment: `pgrep -f -d ' ' /'main.py' | xargs kill`?

Comment: Well, not sure if the `-d` is even needed but I don't use xargs :-)

Comment: What about just `pkill -f /main.py`

Comment: xargs works, thanks.
@Cyrus if you want to post as answer... i can make it an accepted answer.

Comment: From my point of view `-d ' '` is not necessary and `pkill` is simpler.